# Book with a yellow outline and a digital-looking face as a cover, people's bodies are digitalised

Tags: story-identification, books

I am looking for a sci-fi story about the future. It was about this future where people on Earth were able to travel to the moon, and I think the moon was like a theme park or something now.

It was about this guy who meets a girl. Their bodies, as well as every future human, aren’t just bones, blood and veins. They are somehow digital. Can’t remember exactly, but pretty much at the end, the girl dies because her body needed something, and the guy she befriended watched her as she died.